# Why Update() doesnt set .text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a Script Coin-Counter connected with a Text. Every time the Player and the Coin are colliding the coinScore decreases by 1. If I want to display the coinScore in Update() this doesn't work. Why?

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class CoinScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text coinScorer;

    private int coinScore;
    private int oldCoinScore;
    
    void Update()
    {   
        coinScorer.text = coinScore.ToString(); // This doesn't work.
        oldCoinScore = coinScore;            
                
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            coinScore += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);   
            //coinScorer.text = coinScore.ToString(); //This works.

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collision method is destroying this game object.

There is no update to run after that.